# Special way to solve systems of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

If we have a system of two  differential equations and it can be written in the form:
$$\frac{dx}{f_1(x,y,t)}=\frac{dy}{f_2(x,y,t)}=\frac{dt}{f_3(x,y,t)}=\gamma$$
Then we can conclude that:
$$\frac{\alpha_1dx+\alpha_2dy+\alpha_3dt}{\alpha_1f_1(x,y,t)+\alpha_2f_2(x,y,t)+\alpha_3f_3(x,y,t)}=\gamma$$
Now if we choose the correct $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$, Then we can get a  solution. I don't understand if there is an easy way to get the correct coefficients of it is purely a guesswork. Here's an example:
$$\frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{z-x-y}}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{2}=\gamma \Rightarrow \frac{\alpha_1dx+\alpha_2dy+\alpha_3dz}{\alpha_1(1+\sqrt{z-x-y})+\alpha_2+2\alpha_3}=\gamma$$
Then one easy tripple of coefficients is:
$$\alpha_1=0 ;\\ \alpha_2=2 ;\\ \alpha_3=-1$$
Then after substitution we get:
$$2dy-dz=d(2y-z)=0 \Rightarrow 2y-z=C_1$$
To get the full solution of the system, we need one more tripple of coefficients but I don't know what logic to use to find the most appropriate one. Can you help not only with this particular example but with this method as a whole? Also if you know how is it called because I can't even find it online to educate myself.

Comment: Yes, it is guesswork and it only works in examples that are designed to work. Otherwise this system is as generically unsolvable in symbolic terms as any other generic system of dimension 2 or 3 (or higher). // Usually you find such a system in the method of characteristics, and named as Lagrange equation (or Lagrange-Charpit if the first-order PDE is not linear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\alpha_3 = 1$, $\alpha_1 = -1$, $\alpha_2 = -1$
and equate it with $dx/(1+\sqrt{z-x-y})$

you will get this type of equation, $dx/(1+\sqrt{(z-x-y))} = (dz-dx-dy)/\sqrt{(z-x-y)}$

Rewrite $(dz-dx-dy)$ as $d(z-x-y)$ and consider $t = z-x-y$.
substitute it and solve it using variable separable method, integrate it and you will get your second answer.

Comment: Is "$z-y=2\sqrt{z-y-x}+c_2$" the second answer? Because that's what I get but my textbook says it's without the "$z$" on the left.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to equate differential forms such as $\ \frac{dx}{f_1(x,y,t)},$$\frac{dy}{f_2(x,y,t)},$ or $\ \frac{dt}{f_3(x,y,t)}\ $ to a *constant* $\ \gamma\ $.  Depending on context,
$$
\frac{dx}{f_1(x,y,t)}=\frac{dy}{f_2(x,y,t)}=\frac{dt}{f_3(x,y,t)}
$$
might be equivalent to the differential equations
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=\frac{f_1(x,y,t)}{f_3(x,y,t)}\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=\frac{f_2(x,y,t)}{f_3(x,y,t)}\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $ are functions of $\ t\ $, or to
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{ds}&=f_1(x,y,t)\\
\frac{dy}{ds}&=f_2(x,y,t)\\
\frac{dt}{ds}&=f_2(x,y,t)\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ x,y\ $ and $\ t\ $ are functions of $\ s\ $.  In this latter case, you could write
$$
\frac{dx}{f_1(x,y,t)}=\frac{dy}{f_2(x,y,t)}=\frac{dt}{f_3(x,y,t)}=ds\  ,
$$
but I'm not aware of any context where
$$
\frac{dx}{f_1(x,y,t)}=\frac{dy}{f_2(x,y,t)}=\frac{dt}{f_3(x,y,t)}=\gamma
$$
makes sense when $\ \gamma\ $ is a *fixed constant*.

Comment: Well I'm not saying that $\gamma$ is a constant. Just some number. The idea is to pick the constants $\alpha_n$ such that you can have the the upper differentail be equal to "$0\cdot \gamma$" so the function is equal to a constant. If we can make it two times, we get a system of two solutions.